# Cannon rotation around pirate ship

Tags: libgdx, rotation

[image: Visual description]

I have a pirate ship, which has cannons, which work when the ship isn't rotated but when it is they stay (as expected) at 0 degrees. I need them to rotate around the center of the pirate ship when it rotates, so they are still in line with the cannons on the image of the ship. Put simply, what I need is this:

1. Cannons to stay the same rotation relative to the ship (as shown in the picture captioned "What I want"
2. Cannons to stay the same position relative to the ship when it moves
3. The cannons have a Vector2 in them named `forwardDirection` and I need this to always point the same direction relative to the ship
4. For the position and rotation, It should be the same as in Unity 3D & other game engines when you parent something to something else, as in it is always the same relative position and rotation to the parent.

I have absolutely no idea on how to do this, so I need help. Also this explanation might not be clear so if theres anything which doesn't make sense then comment it and I'll change it so it does.

Comment: I don't get the difference between the "what I want" and "what happens" :/

Comment: The difference is the direction and position of the cannons (Each cannon is represented by an arrow)

Comment: And the cannons are separate sprites?

Comment: The actual visuals for the cannons are on the main ship sprite, the actual cannons are just positions and directions which represent where the cannonballs will shoot from.

Comment: You my friend need to use sin and cos calculations for each and every cannon to get their new locations for bullet origin. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have 10 cannons and each cannon is stored as an object in a List.

For sake of ease let's say cannon1 is List.get(0) (getting first cannon)

```
float newX = calculateDistanceX(ship.velocity, cannon1.currentAngle) + cannon1.xPosition;

float newY = calculateDistanceY(ship.velocity, cannon1.currentAngle) + cannon1.yPosition;

cannon1.setX(newX);

cannon1.setY(newY);

/**
 * Calculates the offset which needs to be added to the X position according
 * to the angle .
 * 
 * @param velocity
 *            The velocity
 * @param angle
 *            The angle
 * @return The offset which needs to be added
 */
protected float calculateDistanceX(float velocity, float angle) {
    return velocity * MathUtils.cos(MathUtils.degreesToRadians * angle);
}

/**
 * Calculates the offset which needs to be added to the Y position according
 * to the angle.
 * 
 * @param velocity
 *            The velocity
 * @param angle
 *            The angle
 * @return The offset which needs to be added
 */
protected float calculateDistanceY(float velocity, float angle) {
    return velocity * MathUtils.sin(MathUtils.degreesToRadians * angle);
}
```

Now this way you will be able to move your cannon with the ship. This formula will change the location of your cannon when you move your ship up and down. Do this for all your cannons and you will get their locations.

There may be better way to do this, but this is how I do in my game and it works for a single cannon perfectly.

Hope this gives you a basic idea of how to approach the problem. (The math bit of it, is basically resolving sin and cos components i.e. basic physics)

Comment: Thanks - looks great. Two questions I have are as follows: How do I find the angle/direction of the cannons and what is velocity?

Comment: Your ship must be moving with some speed right? Let's say 2 pixel per sec or something. That is velocity. As far as angle are concerned you will have to keep the angles of cannon, they will be same as the angle ship is facing. You still need to test it.

Comment: Oh I see, but the ship doesn't always move in the same direction or even at the same speed so I'd need to get the position relative to the ship's position

Comment: Yes so when you change the direction of the ship you will change direction of cannon, when you move your ship up and down with some speed, the cannon should also move with the same speed.

Comment: Ok give whatever you understood a try. Unless you try coding you won't understand properly :)